# GeoFire orderByChild filtering

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, geofire

I seem to have stumbled on an issue with GeoFire, in that I can't seem to filter my GeoFire queries. On my platform users create posts and their location is set with geofire, and because of that, it is possible that there are many thousands of posts which I don't want to filter on the client-side..

I'd like to `orderByChild('created')` and `limitToLast('10')` so it doesn't take too long on the client-side..

What I have so far is:

```
  this.geoFire = new GeoFire(this.database.database.ref()
  .child('location'))
  this.geoFire.query({
    center: [this.userLocation.lat, this.userLocation.lng],
    radius: 7
  })
  .on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {
    this.subscription = this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+key)
    .orderByChild('created')
    this.subscription.once('value', (snapshot) => {
          this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val())
    });
  })
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

My database for locations looks like this:

[image]

and for posts:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I filter `orderByChild('score') or 'created'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Firebase query retrieves (possibly) multiple child nodes from a certain location, based on conditions you specify. You already have the complete path to the post here: `database.ref('/posts/'+key)`. You cannot combine already knowing what post you want to retrieve with querying for posts based on conditions.

Your best bet here is to retrieve all posts that are within range, and then filter the top 10 most recent ones on the client.

Comment: That seems highly inefficient though, doesn't it? If there are 10-20,000 posts in a 5 mile radius it would take a while.. wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it would. The alternative is to keep multiple geo-indexes, based on recency of the post. Geofire is already doing something quite magical by filtering on two values, which usually isn't possible in Firebase. You're trying to add another value (recency) to the mix, which is beyond what the library was made for.